# Generating epoch time in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Am an intermediate-level swift ios developer , now am developing an app where i need to use epoch time that is generated from Current Date and Time, For that i have tried the following code

```
var date = NSDate()
var timestamp = (floor(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
```

and  getting a Float value some thing like 1411032097112.0..
But in my case i need only the integer part of this result. Is this the best way for achieving this or is there any other best solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about

```
var timestamp = UInt64(floor(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
```

---

*Edit :*

As @MartinR points out in his answer, `Int64` will be a better choice than `Int` due to space constraint in 32 bit devices. `UInt64` will be better still, since you are getting a time interval which will always be positive.

Comment: In this case, time interval will always be positive.  In general time interval may be negative.

Answer (score 9):

You can just convert the floating point value to `Int64`:

```
let date = NSDate()
let timestamp = Int64(date.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0)
println(timestamp)
// 1411034055289
```

You should use `Int64` or `UInt64` instead of `Int` because the latter is only 32-bit on 32-bit devices, which is not large enough for the time in milliseconds.